# Getting 505 error with ugly messages while validating custom Enum annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to apply custom enum annotation on query parameter attribute, and I am trying to restrict specific values to be accepted to proceed further but i get 500 error `with below details. Does anyone have any clue about this?

```
//controller interface

@RestController @Validated @RequestMapping("/api/v1") public interface ReferenceDataController{

@GetMapping(value="/reference-data", produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ReferenceData> getReferenceData(@QueryParam(value = "type of master data")@CustomMasterDataValidator String masterData,@NotNull @Valid  @RequestHeader String correlationId);
}

//service impl

public class ReferenceDataServiceImpl implements ReferenceDataService {

@Override
public ResponseEntity<ReferenceData> getReferenceData(String masterData) {
    try {
        //TO-DO

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        log.error(" Exception while queuing request", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .body(new ReferenceData(masterData,null,"500", "Internal Server Error", "UNK-001", e.getMessage()));
    }
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED).body(new ReferenceData(masterData,null,"200", "Accepted", null, null));
}}
//class to restrict specific value

@Target({ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.PARAMETER}) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Documented @Constraint(validatedBy = MasterDataValidator.class) public @interface CustomMasterDataValidator { public String message() default "Invalid Type for masterdate: IT should be voucherCode,productType,categoryCode,elementGroup,udas or masterSeasons" ;

Class<?>[] groups() default {}; Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

//class to define custom annotation

public class MasterDataValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomMasterDataValidator, String>{

@Override public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) { return Arrays.asList("voucherCode","productType","categoryCode","elementGroup","udas","masterSeasons").contains(value); } }
```

while hitting request i get 500 error with ugly codes.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "systemErrorCode": 500,
      "typeId": "SERVER_ERROR",
      "message": "Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ConstraintDeclarationException: HV000151: A method overriding another method must not redefine the parameter constraint configuration, but method ReferenceDataControllerImpl#getReferenceData(String, String) redefines the configuration of ReferenceDataController#getReferenceData(String, String)."
    }
  ]
}
```

| `Column A` | `Column B` |
| --- | --- |
| `Cell 1` | `Cell 2` |
| `Cell 3` | `Cell 4` |

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `@RestController` and `@Validated` annotations on the interface level as they are intended for the class level:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html

If you move them to ReferenceDataServiceImpl then the issue should be resolved.
Actually it's reasonable to move `@RequestMapping` to the class level as well, unless you really need multiple implementations of your controller. (It is actually possible to define this at interface level [since Spring 5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#general-web-revision-1) but is does not mean that is always makes sense).

P.S. Even though it is not related to your error, I would also make the following improvements in your code:

- Remove `@ResponseBody` annotation (as `@RestController` already includes it)
- Rename `ReferenceDataService` to `ReferenceDataController` as typically service level is not what produces external APIs but what is called from the controller level.